# Where can I find this cursive capital Z found in a paper?

Tags: symbols, letters

My google-fu has failed me, and I can't for the life of me find this Z symbol/letter that is used in Sequeira, P., Yeh, E., & Gervasio, M. T. (2019). Interestingness Elements for Explainable Reinforcement Learning through Introspection. In IUI Workshops (p. 7).
I looked at math symbols, greek and hebrew letters,... Does anyone know how I can produce that symbol or at least how it is called? Thank you a lot in advance!

[image]

Comment: The document seem to have `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`. The symbol is a script Z, `\mathcal{Z}`. The precise shape is actually *unimportant*; use `\mathcal{Z}` and your readers will understand.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was a predefined symbol that I HAD to use, like the R for real numbers, for example. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate the picture (also fixing the obvious typos, where subscripts should be superscripts for consistency; the dots between the `\times` symbols should be centered):

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

In addition, as is the case with many RL scenarios, let us 
assume that, at each time-step~$t$, the agent observes its 
environment through a finite set of \emph{features} 
$Z_t^i=z^i$, $i=1,2,\dots,N$, each taking values in some 
feature space~$\mathcal{Z}^i$. The observation-space thus 
corresponds to the cartesian product 
$\mathcal{Z}=\mathcal{Z}^1\times\dots\times\mathcal{Z}^N$.
When this is the case, the structure exhibited by such
\emph{factored~MDPs} can also be exploited to derive
interesting aspects related to specific observation elements.

\end{document}
```

There is nothing really special in the shape of the “script Z”. It's just a fancier counterpart to the italic “Z” used in the line above.

Without `newtx` (comment out the fourth line), we'd get from the same input

[image]

If instead `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` is replaced by `\usepackage{fourier}`, we'd get

[image]

There's no “universal” meaning of the “script Z” in your picture.

You mention in a comment the symbol commonly used for the real numbers. That's a different case. In the last two or three decades, it has become common to use ℝ (or variant thereof, so long as it's *double-struck*). While it's understood by almost everybody to mean the real numbers, authors might use a different symbol for the same object. Lang's “Algebra” uses standard boldface **Z**, **Q**, **R** and **C** for the number sets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive answer! I didnt even notice that the subscripts need to be superscripts.